# Java Development Kit (JDK) is required rather than a JRE . creating welogic server

Tags: eclipse, weblogic12c

i am creating weblogic server in eclipse to deploy web dynamic project but i am facing problem   "Java Development Kit (JDK) is required rather than a JRE"
[creating weblogic server in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fGi1.png)

Comment: Then you should install the JDK and point to it instead of the JRE

Comment: A JDK path is what's specified in the image. That version of Weblogic Server might require, or only support, an older JDK. Try JDK 1.8 instead of Java 10.

Comment: Check the environment path variables on your machine to make sure that the path to a JDK is there and also check to make sure that there isn't some other strange path variables in there causing a problem. I have had this problem a few times and it was usually because the path wasn't in the environment or there was some other oracle created path there that was causing a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JDK contains the javac compiler and other tools that a JRE doesn't contain. Maybe weblogic needs them.
You can download the JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Make sure you pick a version compatible with your weblogic server.
After installation, in Eclipse, open Preferences > Java > Installed JREs and add it (and maybe choose it as default).
It maybe necessary to choose it in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments in the Execution Environment you use in you project, or directly in you project, or maybe in the run configuration you use.